# response of ajax object property access

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I am sending ajax request to controller and i am getting this response

```
{
    "countryRegion": "United Kingdom",
    "address": "DG10 9LT, GB",
    "streetAddress": null,
    "locality": null,
    "adminDistrict": "Scotland",
    "postalCode": "DG10 9LT"
}
```

this is my ajax

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/Account/ReverseGeocode",
  data: {
    "latitude": lat,
    "longitude": long
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result.CountryRegion);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error has occured!!!");
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this hoe i am returning my response in controller

```
   var data = new AddressResult()
                    {
                      
                        AdminDistrict = location.Address.AdminDistrict,
                        CountryRegion = location.Address.CountryRegion,
                      
                    };
                    return Json(data);
```

how i can get CountryRegion  property. i tried

- `result.CountryRegion`
- `res=JSON.parse(result); res.CountryRegion`
- `res=JSON.stringify(result); res.CountryRegion`
- `data[0].CountryRegion`
  all of that not working. and when i `console.log(type of result)` it is `[Object Object]`

Comment: Your first attempt was correct, except that `C` should be `c`. `result.countryRegion`.

Comment: yes it turns out to be a matter of letters. thank you